# How can I test and use a Perl regular expression interactively?

Tags: regular-expressions, commands

Say I have a buffer with text. I would like to test a regular expression (ideally Perl type) against my buffer and have Emacs highlight the matches on it.

For example, the following regexp ([taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)):

```
(?<=\.) {2,}(?=[A-Z])
```

would match as follows on the following text:

[image]

This regular expression in particular matches at least two spaces occurring after period `(.)` and before an upper case letter.

Does Emacs provide an **interactive** regular expression matcher for **Perl** regular expressions?

If the answer to the latter is no:

1. Is there a reason why **native** support of **Perl** regular expressions wasn't (ever) considered in Emacs? (considering that it is a well known standard in Unix/Linux)
2. How could one proceed about building one such Perl regexp matcher? (perhaps calling Perl under the hood, or pre-converting the Perl regexp to a supported variant?)

Comment: Emacs regexps predate Perl by some time, and I'm assuming they haven't been changed for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out https://github.com/joddie/pcre2el (I haven't used it, so I can't vouch for it).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two nice packages for working with perl kind of regexes effectively, which should be used together - [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el) and it's extension - [visual-regexp-steroids](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/). They are great addition to emacs:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, visual-regexp uses emacs regexp and the steroids version can use PCRE or Python regex as backend.

Answer (score 7):

`re-builder` allows on the fly construction of emacs lisp style regular expressions. I don't know if there is an equivalent package for building Perl regular expressions interactively.

See http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/04/12/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder/ for more discussion.