# "Args out of range" error when replacing with visual-regexp-steroids

Tags: regular-expressions

I have been trying to use [`visual-regexp-steroids`](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/) without luck (a thread on this package can be found [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/how-can-i-test-and-use-a-perl-regular-expression-interactively))

When I do `vr/replace (C-c p)`, I get a prompt in the minibuffer. I can enter regexps and Emacs shows interactively every match in the buffer. So far so good.

The problem comes when I click `RET` and then enter another string (the one I want to replace my matches with). If I now do `RET` (to do the actual replacements), I get the following message in the mini-buffer:

```
Args out of range #<killed buffer>, 0, 0
```

Why? How can I debug the problem and get it to work?

---

- Update: I have opened an issue in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/issues/13)

Comment: How is this related to multiple cursors? To debug the error, do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then recreate the error. You can then paste the generated backtrace info in your question above to help people further assist you.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong. I think I'd file an issue on github

Comment: You are right @kaushalmodi This specific `vr` command  is not about multiple-cursors. I removed the tag.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug with the maintainer (and then delete this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my shell init file (`.zshenv`  in my case, since I am using `zsh`) was printing one line to `stdout` every time I logged in, and this was confusing the parsing. Once I removed the `echo` line, everything worked well.

I am leaving this as an answer here in case anyone else runs into the same problem.